# Referencing individual cells of a tilemap and changing texture

Tags: java, libgdx, tilemap

I have a tilemap and am trying to proceduraly generate islands on it by changing the texture of the tiles and marking it as land ( I want to do this without texture atlas for now). How do you change the texture of an individual tile and how do you mark the tile to distinguish it from other tiles within map as land . I have tried to do this but for some reason even though I reference an individual tile all tiles are changing textures.

```
private static TiledMapTileLayer baseLayer;
private static TextureRegion landTextureReg;
private static Texture landTexture;
private static TiledMapTile landTile;

public static TiledMap generateMap(){
landTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("hex_land_trans.png"));
landTextureReg = new TextureRegion(landTexture);
TiledMap map = new TmxMapLoader().load("ocean_hex_map.tmx");
baseLayer = (TiledMapTileLayer)map.getLayers().get(0);
baseLayer.getCell(1, 1).getTile().setTextureRegion(landTextureReg);
return map;
}
```

Comment: How are you currently referencing your tiles?  Can you provide some code on what you are currently doing?

Comment: Added code to question :)

Comment: @Jon can you see the code now? and sorry didnt know to put "@Jon" for you to get notifications :/ at least now i know :)

Comment: Yes, so you are building your maps in Tiles, and then importing them.  I don't know much about Tiled, but you should be able to set a Tile Type in there and then load the texture based on the type you set.

Comment: @Jon I set the land tile as a tile type in tiled how do I mark certain tiles as land for later reference and change individual tile textures/types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change the texture region of the `TiledMapTile`, change the `TiledMapTile of the`Cell`. Changing the tile itself will as you say cause all`Cell`s that reference that`TiledMapTile` to be updated.

```
private static TiledMapTileLayer baseLayer;
private static TextureRegion landTextureReg;
private static Texture landTexture;
private static TiledMapTile landTile;

public static TiledMap generateMap(){
    landTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("hex_land_trans.png"));
    landTextureReg = new TextureRegion(landTexture);
    TiledMap map = new TmxMapLoader().load("ocean_hex_map.tmx");
    TiledMapTileSet tileSet = map.getTileSets().getTileSet("your_tile_set");
    baseLayer = (TiledMapTileLayer)map.getLayers().get(0);


    Cell newCell = new Cell();
// Do this if the landTexture is in the tileset already but just not used for the
    // specific tile (you likely want all your tiles in one tilesheet).
    newCell.setTile(tileSet.getTile(42)); // Or whatever the ID you're trying to change to

// This would work if you want to load the tile sperately as you seem to do right now
StaticTiledMapTile myTile = new StaticTiledMapTile(landTextureReg);
    newCell.setTile(myTile); 

    // Set the cell at the coordinates you want to affect to a new tile, this won't change all the tile, just this cell
baseLayer.setCell(1, 1, newCell); 
    return map;
```

}

Comment: will try when I get home thankyou :) and how would I go about setting some sort of marker for which tiles are which terrain?

Comment: If you're using the **Tiled** map editor, right click your tile in the tile set and select Properties. Then you can add custom properties (key-value pairs) that can be read from the tile by calling `getProperties()` on the tile.